# Zeroth G-equivariant Stable Stem

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, equivariant-homotopy

Let G be a finite group. Can anyone give me a motivation and rigorous proof of the Burnside ring A(G) is isomorphic to the zeroth G-equivariant stable stem ?

Comment: Just a guess, but have you looked into the lecture notes from the Alaska conference hosted on Peter May's website?

Comment: Have you looked at tom Dieck's "Transformation Groups"? The relevant sections are I.2, II.8 and IV.2.

Comment: @ White: I can't able to understand the cofiber property of "Equivariant euler chracteristics".Can you give me any rigorous and lucid proof?